# Solution to overdetermined systems

Tags: math, octave, scilab, maxima

How to find solution to overdetermined systems in Macsyma, Scilab, Octave?

Answer (score 4):

The backslash operator gives the least-squares solution in [Scilab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab).

Comment: same syntax for Matlab/Octave

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what type of system it is. If it is non-linear, you are in a very serious mess. In the linear case, You are trying to solve the system Ax = y, where A is not invertible. Even though it is not invertible, it admits a pseudo inverse, which you can **stably** compute using SVD.